# Python testing whether a string is one of a certain set of values

Tags: python, string, equality

I'm learning python on codecademy and my current task is this:

> Write a function, shut_down, that takes one parameter (you can use
>   anything you like; in this case, we'd use s for string). The shut_down
>   function should return **"Shutting down..."** when it gets **"Yes"**, **"yes"**,
>   or **"YES"** as an argument, and **"Shutdown aborted!"** when it gets **"No"**,
>   **"no"**, or **"NO"**.
>
> If it gets anything other than those inputs, the function should
>   return **"Sorry, I didn't understand you."**

Seemed easy to me but somehow I still can't do it.

My code I made to test the function:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "Yes" or s == "yes" or s == "YES":
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s == "No" or "no" or "NO":
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."

i = input("Do you want to shutdown?")
print(i) #was to test the input
print(shut_down(i)) #never returns "Sorry, I didn't understand you"
```

It works fine for the no's and yes', but somehow if I put a space before any yes or even if I just type in "a" it prints "Shutdown aborted!" although it should print "Sorry, I didn't understand you".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you guys, I will accept an answer in a few minutes. You helped a lot and I don't think I will ever forget the '==' again, lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to write `s == "no"` in your first `elif:`

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "Yes" or s == "yes" or s == "YES":
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s == "No" or "no" or "NO":             # you forgot the s== in this line
        return "Shutdown aborted!" 
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

Do this:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "Yes" or s == "yes" or s == "YES":
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s == "No" or s == "no" or s == "NO":       # fixed it 
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

This is because:

```
elif s == "No" or "no" or "NO":  #<---this
elif s == "No" or True or True:  #<---is the same as this
```

Since this is the accepted answer I'll elaborate to include standard practices: The convention for comparing strings regardless of capitalization (equalsIgnoreCase) is to use [`.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) like this

```
elif s.lower() == "no":
```

Comment: thank you, worked. I didn't know I have to type in (in this example) 's == ' before each or in python.

Comment: @Davlog But you did so in the `Yes` line?!

Comment: @Davlog : if an answer solved your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: @Stephan Another option could be `if s in ('Yes', 'yes', 'YES')` resp. `if s in ('No', 'no', 'NO')`.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Yeah, I know. But I have to wait 10 min.

Comment: @glglgl hmmm... old c++ behavior, I really thought I don't have to in python :p

Comment: @Stephan yeah, i didn't forget that

Answer (score 6):

Instead of checking for different combinations of capitalization you could uses the `lower` function to return a copy of `s` in lowercase and compare against that.

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s.lower() == "yes":
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s.lower() == "no":       
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

This is much cleaner and easier to debug. Alternatively you could use `upper` also and compare against `"YES"` and `"NO"`.

---

If this doesn't help because of matching cases like `nO` then I'd go with the `in` statement:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s in ("yes","Yes","YES"):
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s in ("no","No","NO"):       
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

Comment: I would have done the same, but the assignment is quite specific.

Comment: @MatLecu Read [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) for why that works.

Comment: @MatLecu you may have a point so added an alternative using `in`.

Comment: Sorry my phrasing was bad: I know why it works, but it seems like the assignment says it shouldn't work with nO. The edit is still nicer than a bunch of or though.

Answer (score 4):

Python evaluates non empty strings to be `True`, so your `elif` condition is always evaluated to `True`.

```
>>> bool('No')
True

>>> bool('NO')
True
```

Doing a boolean `or` with a `True` value would always return `True`, so it never reaches the `else` condition and gets stuck on the `elif` one.

You need to test the conditions using.

`elif choice == 'no' or choice == 'NO' or choice == 'No':`

**EDIT** - As glglgl pointed out in the comment, `==` binds harder than `or`, so your condition gets evaluated as `(s == 'No') or 'no' or 'NO'` and not `s == ('No' or 'no' or 'NO')`, in which case you would have gotten to the `else` part even for a user input of `'NO'`.

Comment: Maybe it is noteworth that due to the [operator precedence rules](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `==` binds harder so that it evaluates to `(s == "No") or ("no") or ("NO")` and not to `s == ("No" or "no" or "NO")`. The latter one would boil down to `s == "No"`.

Comment: @glglgl : Added in the answer. Thanks. :)