# Or comparision of input values

Tags: python

```
compareusr = str(input())

compare = "austin" or "cloud"
if compare == compareusr:
    print("it worked")
else:
    print("it didnt work")
```

This may be a stupid question. I’m not the most fluent in python however I thought I knew enough for this comparison work.

Does anyone know why when the input=cloud the code does not work?!?!? It works with and, but why does it not work with or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python testing whether a string is one of a certain set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902492/python-testing-whether-a-string-is-one-of-a-certain-set-of-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612144/logical-operators-in-python

Comment: `compare = "austin" or "cloud"` is in effect same as `compare = "austin"`. Create a list and check condition with `in`.

Comment: Also: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612144/logical-operators-in-python)

Comment: @PatrickArtner in this case `or` functions as the [elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813117/10630900)

Answer (score 0):

Operator `or` returns logical value. In your code `compare` is equal to `True` because the strings are not empty. Conversion `input` to `str` is redundant.

```
compareusr = input()

compare = ["austin", "cloud"]
if compareusr in compare:
    print("it worked")
else:
    print("it didnt work")
```

Comment: Actually, `or` functions as the elvis operator in this case. This means that `compare` is equal to `"austin"` because it is not the `None` type.