# Why is my "If" statement being triggered?

Tags: python, string, int

This is my first post, so I apologize if I do anything incorrectly.

I am currently writing a simple program for a college class. The instructions for this specific part say:

> The value of the entry MUST be “1”, or “2”, or “3”. There are different ways you can test for this.
>
> You may create different validation techniques if you like as long as they work. If the entry is not valid, respond with an
> appropriate error message and re-prompt.

Now when I prompt the user to enter a selection (lets say they enter "1") it thinks it is an invalid input.

I personally think it should take the answer as an `int` value but the instructions say it should not. Am I missing something small here?

I have tried editing the code with different `'` and `"` marks. I think I might be making a small syntax error but I can't put my finger on it.

```py
cont= str("y")
cart = int(0)
item_total = int(0) 
order_total= float(0)

cont=input("Would you like to place an order? ")
while(cont.lower() == "y"):
  print("Order for John Doe")
  print("1. Savannah")
  print("2. Thin Mints")
  print("3. Tagalongs")
  item_n=input("Please choose a flavor ")
  if(item_n != "1" or item_n != "2" or item_n != "3"):
    print("Invalid entry, please try again")
  else:
    new_item=int(input("How many would you like (1-10)"))
```

I expect that if you enter a 1, 2, or 3 it will go into the else nest, but it does not. I can also post more of the professor's instructions if needed.

Comment: `I expect that if you enter a 1, 2, or 3 it will go into the else nest` If you input 1, `item_n != "1" or item_n != "2" or item_n != "3"` evaluates to `False or True or True` -> `True`.

Comment: Change or to and.

Comment: Better yet, use `item_n not in ('1', '2', '3')`. Don't do `item_n not in '123'`. That will match `12`, `23` and `123`

Comment: I swapped my if and else statements and changed the "!=" to "==" and it seems to be working properly! I see what you mean though, thank you for your answer. I also am unsure how to mark this question as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python testing whether a string is one of a certain set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902492/python-testing-whether-a-string-is-one-of-a-certain-set-of-values)

Answer (score 2):

you should use this

```
item_n=int(input("Please choose a flavor "))
```

instead of this

```
item_n=input("Please choose a flavor ")
```

as input function takes strings so you need to convert it into int

and use AND instead of OR in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AND not an OR. Because it should not 1 AND not 2 AND not 3 for an error.

Comment: I swapped my if and else statements and changed the "!=" to "==" and it seems to be working properly! I see what you mean though, thank you for your answer. I also am unsure how to mark this question as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cont= str("y")
cart = int(0)
item_total = int(0)
order_total= float(0)

cont=input("Would you like to place an order? ")
while(cont.lower() == "y"):
  print("Order for John Doe")
  print("1. Savannah")
  print("2. Thin Mints")
  print("3. Tagalongs")
  item_n=input("Please choose a flavor ")

  if(item_n not in ["1","2","3"]):
    print("Invalid entry, please try again")
  else:
    new_item=int(input("How many would you like (1-10)"))
```